# How to find text using attribute value

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir, rubymine

I'm not quite sure what the issue is with my code, obviously I've gone wrong somewhere. Here's the code;

```
Then(/^the room selection should be switched to auto assign$/) do
  autoassign = @browser.iframe(:id , 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:class , 'col-md-8 column').span(:id , 'selected_room').html
  Watir::Wait.for_condition(10 , 2 , "Waiting for room to auto assign") {
    autoassign.attribute_value(:id).eql?('Auto Assignment')
  }
end
```

And here's the error;

```
undefined method `attribute_value' for "<span id=\"selected_room\">Auto Assignment</span>":String (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autoassign` is of type `String`. [Ruby `String` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html) has no method named `attribute_value`.

Try removing `.html` from the first line so it looks likes this:

```
autoassign = @browser.iframe(:id , 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:class , 'col-md-8 column').span(:id , 'selected_room')
Watir::Wait.for_condition(10 , 2 , "Waiting for room to auto assign") {
autoassign.attribute_value(:id).eql?('Auto Assignment')
}
```